# XSL Read processing instruction with spaces in it

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

In a source xml document I have a processing instruction containing spaces - 
    `<?Tag To Delete?>`

How can I read and process this processing instruction with xslt?

If I try using processing-instruction('Tag To Delete') I get an error - No processing instruction will ever be named 'Tag To Delete'. Invalid QName {Tag To Delete}

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

It's not entirely clear what you want to do with this procesing instruction once you select it, but a processing instruction's name is the portion from the `<?` up to the first space (so in this case the name is `Tag`). The portion after that first space is its content. So an XPath that would match that processing instruction is:

```
processing-instruction('Tag')[. = 'To Delete']
```

Answer (score 0):

**In case there could be undetermined number of space character in the string value of the processing instruction, such as in**:

```
<?Tag To Delete?>

<?Tag   To    Delete    ?>

<?Tag To            Delete ?>
```

**any of these variants can be selected with:**

```
processing-instruction('Tag')[normalize-space() = 'To Delete']
```

**Here is a brief, XSLT-based verification:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select=
  "/*/processing-instruction('Tag')[normalize-space() = 'To Delete']"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<t>
    <?Tag To Delete?>
    <?Tag   Not To    Delete    ?>
    <?Tag   To    Delete    ?>
    <?Tag To            Delete ?>
</t>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated and the result of this evaluation (the selected nodes) is copied to the output**:

```
<?Tag To Delete?><?Tag To    Delete    ?><?Tag To            Delete ?>
```